# Struggling to connect to Google-Cloud-Platform on windows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api

I live in Kenya. I struggle to connect to google cloud services most times failing  but want to bypass this issue when using the vision api on windows. Most times I that I run, I get
`google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses`
I have tried

```
response = client.text_detection(image=image, timeout=6000000000)
```

but still get the same error. 
I have also set a ReceiveTimeout value in internet settings, even turning off all network protection when working on my project.

How can I get around this

Comment: Do not turn off network protection. That is not your problem. You have an unreliable network connection to the Internet or a firewall preventing you from connecting to Google's endpoint.